# Shopware 6. Migration error: An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS, Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, shopware6

I get this error running migration ./bin/console database:migrate

```
Migration error: An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT  
   EXISTS `a1filter_property_group_option_tag` (                               
      `option_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,                                         
      `tag_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,                                            
      `created_at` datetime(3) NOT NULL,                                       
      `updated_at` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,                                   
      PRIMARY KEY (`option_id`, `tag_id`),                                     
      CONSTRAINT `fk.a1filter_property_group_option_tag.tag_id` FOREIGN KEY (  
  `tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE       
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;':        
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `devxxx_yyy`.`a1  
  filter_property_group_option_tag` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is in  
  correctly formed")
```

Can someone give an advice?

Comment: check this question might help:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203509/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have this referential action with your foreign key

```sql
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

because the column is not nullable. You may want to change to cascade instead.

```sql
ON DELETE CASCADE
```